# VS .NET class designer

Tags: visual-studio, associations, class-designer

Assume that class Being has a property of type Habitat. Both classes are implemented in their own .cs files. When I drag and drop the two classes from the class designer onto a new Class diagram, I do not see an association line from Being to Habitat, whereas there is an association in code. Am I doing something wrong, or this simply isn't implemented in VS yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the property connection, right-click on the property; "show as association" or "show as collection association" (as appropriate)

Comment: @Marc: You seem to run faster by foot than me on my bike (see my avatar) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's off by default. Right click on the property and choose "Show as association"

Answer (score 0):

The class diagram doesn't show "lines" between every instance (property) of a type and its type.  This would get very, very messy very quickly.

If "Being" derived from "Habitat" (which wouldn't make sense), it would show a line for that.  It shows lines for inheritance, not each individual field/property.

Comment: You described the default behavior, but as I said on my answer you can turn "Show as association" on for those properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

Habitat is a property in Being.  They are not associated in the way the designer shows.  The designer shows inheritance.

Comment: The designer will show you an association if you tell it to do so. See my answer.